# Functions that require global assignment as a way of reusing code in R - good or bad practice?

Tags: r, function, global

So I'm running a simulation in R where every time a certain event happens I need to recalculate a number of variables and this event can happen many times within a single iteration of a loop. The code looks something like this.

```
nums = a+b*c;
nums[v:(v+3)] = 1
listicle = lapply(stuff, func)
n = sum(nums)-t
```

It seems sensible, in order not repeat it over and over, I wrap it in some function, so it might look like...

```
updateVars = function(){
    nums <<- a+b*c;
    nums[v:(v+3)] <<- 1
    listicle <<- lapply(stuff, func)
    n <<- sum(nums)-t
}
```

And then whenever I need to update these variables I would just call `updateVars()`.

I was reading the R inferno, though, and in chapter 6 they consider global assignment as bad practice.

I'm unsure, though, how I would keep code short and readable without functions like these. Is there a trick I'm missing or is this a valid exception for use of global assignment?

Thanks,
Nathan

Edit: Reproducible code.

```
a=rnorm(100,3,2)
b=rnorm(100,1,3)
c=rnorm(100,4,2)
updatedef = function()
{
    d<<-a+b-c^2
    e<<-var(a^b)-mean(c)
    f<<-lapply(a+b+c, function(t){rnorm(10,t,t/3)})
}
for (i in 1:400){
    a=a+1
    updatedef()
    print(d+e)
    print(f)
    b=2*b
    updatedef()
    print(d+e)
    print(f)
    c=runif(100)
    print(d+e)
    print(f)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete minimal reproducible example? We don't need your actual code but something that illustrates your issue and is reproducible would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to learn about closures. Good read: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures

Comment: @Apom I can't figure out a particular reason why closures here trump the use of a function as above?

Comment: Unsure they fit your particular need indeed. I need to give it more thought myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two "global variable" issues with your example, and I've rewritten it to avoid both of them. It doesn't make the code any longer really, it seems easier to read (especially for someone unfamiliar with the code) and it definitely feels *safer* to me.

The issues I see are:

- `updatedef` depends on finding the correct values of `a`, `b` and `c` in some parent environment. I changed the definition to make them explicit arguments
- `updatedef` didn't `return` anything, it just replaced the values of `d`, `e`, and `f` in the closest parent environment. I made a list of these values an explicit return.

Here's the code:

```
update_def = function(a, b, c) {
    d = a + b - c^2
    e = var(a^b) - mean(c)
    f = lapply(a + b + c, function(t) rnorm(10, t, t / 3))
    return(list(d = d, e = e, f = f))
}

for (i in 1:4) {
    a = a + 1
    def = update_def(a, b, c)
    with(def, print(d + e))
    print(def$f)

    b = 2 * b
    def = update_def(a, b, c)
    with(def, print(d + e))
    print(def$f)

    c = runif(100)
    def = update_def(a, b, c)
    with(def, print(d + e))
    print(def$f)
}
```

#### Generalizing

I know this was a toy example - perhaps your real code has several more variables than just `a, b, c` that are needed to compute on. In this case, much like the `def` list I created, I'd urge you to use a `list` to store them in. You may even want to create your own class extending a list that has some methods.

In the above example, we could make a `def` class with a custom `print` method that does the two lines that are so often repeated in the code:

```
update_def_c = function(a, b, c) {
    d = a + b - c^2
    e = var(a^b) - mean(c)
    f = lapply(a + b + c, function(t) rnorm(10, t, t / 3))
    def = list(d = d, e = e, f = f)
    class(def) = c("def", "list")
    return(def)
}

print.def = function(def, ...) {
    print(def$d + def$e, ...)
    print(def$f, ...)
}
```

Then, instead of repeated `print(d+e); print(f)`, we could just call `print(def)`. And most importantly, if at a later point we want the print behavior to change, it only needs to be changed in one place. This makes your code more modular.

I think these changes make your code more readable to people in the general R audience. The assumption is always that functions *don't* have side effects (like changing values without explicit assignment). Your `updatedef` is a well-named function in that its name suggests what it does, but its dependence on `a` `b` and `c` isn't clear from its usage, which could confuse someone unfamiliar with the code (maybe even you looking back in a year or two!).